# How to insert listview items into 3 different tables VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, listview

I'm trying to make a library system. I have a listview and it contains items to be inserted into different tables, (b_borrow_tbl, for the books , d_borrow_tbl for the multimedia, and m_borrow_tbl for the module).

I'm using this code to insert items to b_borrow_tbl:

```
       Dim myconnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source = .\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog = librarysystemdb; Integrated Security = True")
    selecteduser = cmb_borrower.SelectedValue
    myconnection.Open()

    For xa = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1

        Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("Insert into b_borrow_tbl (bid,user_id,dateborrowed,aid,status) values(@bid,@user,@dateborrowed,@admin ,'" & "Borrowed" & "')", myconnection)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("bid", ListView1.Items(xa).SubItems(5).Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", selecteduser)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateborrowed", datestring)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("admin", LoginPage.admin)
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myconnection.Close()

    Next
    MsgBox("Transaction Saved")

    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    myconnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: You can essentially repeat code similar to this for each of your other tables, changing  your sqlcommand appropriately for each iteration. Alternately, you could create separate sqlcommand objects *withiin* the loop that insert into different tables, looping through your list just once.

Comment: Thank you sir could you demostrate it

Comment: Done. Take a look at the answer I've posted; I've sketched out one way you might accomplish it.

Comment: I differentiate it by adding a field name called "type" that is how

Comment: I differentiate it by adding a field name "type" (Books, Modules,MultimediA)

Comment: How is that represented in your ListView? Some sample data from your listview would be very helpful, I think. It's a matter of extracting that type and wrapping the INSERTs with a proper chunk of conditional code testing for the particular type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility. Note that I can't give you exact code because I don't know the structure of your other tables...so, with that caveat...

```
   Dim myconnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source = .\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog = librarysystemdb; Integrated Security = True")
selecteduser = cmb_borrower.SelectedValue
myconnection.Open()

For xa = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1

    Dim itemType as String
    itemType = ListView1.Items(xa).Subitems(6).Text ' Not sure abt col #

    if itemType="Books" Then
        Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("Insert into b_borrow_tbl (bid,user_id,dateborrowed,aid,status) values(@bid,@user,@dateborrowed,@admin ,'" & "Borrowed" & "')", myconnection)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("bid", ListView1.Items(xa).SubItems(5).Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", selecteduser)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateborrowed", datestring)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("admin", LoginPage.admin)
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If

    If itemType="Multimedia" Then
        mycommand.SqlCommand="Insert into d_borrow_table( field1,field2,etc) values (@parm1,@parm2,...)
        mycommand.Parameters.Clear()
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1",value)
        ' etc
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

      ' Then repeat by changing command text for third table
      ' clearing/defining parameters, then executing the query
    End If
    myconnection.Close()

Next
MsgBox("Transaction Saved")

ListView1.Items.Clear()
myconnection.Close()

End Sub
```

All we're doing here is "resetting" the "mycommand" variable with a new INSERT statement, clearing the parameters, and redefining them for the second and third inserts. Note that the connection isn't closed until after all three inserts have fired. You'll obviously need to replace the "placeholders" of "field1,field2" and @param1,@param2 etc with the actual fields from your tables, but I think that should give you a push in the right direction.

Comment: thanks david for the quick response, but the problem is that from the listview (which can contain 3 different items it could be books, or modules), the items are categorized as multimedia, books, and modules what i want to happen is, items categorized as books should be inserted only to b_borrow_tbl and multimedia and modules should be inserted to d_ borrow_tbl and m_borrow_tbl respectively

Comment: How do you differentiate between them in your Listview?

Comment: I differentiate it by adding a fieldname called "Type" (Books, Module, Multimedia are its values)

Comment: Item Number  Item Title   Date Borrowed  Due Date       Type                           
ETC0001          ISM             6/24/2015        6/27/2015    Book
DVDVT001     Routeing       6/24/2015         6/27/2015    Multimedia

Comment: Those values are all stored into each string in the ListView? Are they separated by commas or any other delimeter?

Comment: nope hold on a sec im gonna upload it and give you the link

Comment: Well, it isn't ideal, but I think what you'll have to do is pull the type off the end of each string from the ListView from what looks like the last index of a space, and then base some IF statements on that value

Comment: Aha - since each item in the loop is a ListViewItem, you should be able to get the Type as the last SubItems column for each row. Use that value in an IF THEN block around each type of insert.

Comment: I've modified the answer to illustrate how you'd get your Type column as a SubItem from each ListItemView, and use that as the "pivot" in the IF statements controlling which INSERT is performed. Double-check the column/SubItem index number I use to ensure it's the correct value. That might not be perfect, but it should give you another good push!

Comment: AWESOME!! Great to hear. Glad I was able to help.